# How to compare two before / after input values using jquery data

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm working on a form where I need to compare values of an input. Let's say for example, I have an input which comes from the server with value name1 and then the user changes it to name2. How can I get the initial value and the new value? My script below shows my attempt at resolving this, but when I look at the console output oldAddressNameValue does not have the old value and neither does newAddressNameValue.
What am I doing wrong?

```
var $el = $('#inputAddressName');
var oldAddressNameValue = $el.data('oldVal', $el.val());
console.log(oldAddressNameValue);
var newAddressNameValue = $el.change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newValue = $this.data('newVal', $this.val());
});
console.log(newAddressNameValue);
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in `console`?

Comment: Well, I'm not using exactly the console but chrome sources. I'm seeing the scope variables and for oldAddressNameValue I see `m.fn.init[1]` but not name1

Answer (score 0):

The data function assigns the value to the attribute but will then return the element  for jquery chaining.
If you output $el.data('oldVal') directly it should return the value.

```
console.log($el.data('oldVal'))
```

or you can assign the result of the single parameter version of .data() to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside el.change is not executing until the input changes, hence the log is logging nothing, also I'm not so sure about the way you are declaring your variables. This works.

```
var $el = $('#inputAddressName');
var oldAddressNameValue = $el.val(),
    newAddressNameValue;

console.log(oldAddressNameValue);

$el.on('change', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('newVal', $this.val());
    newAddressNameValue = $this.val();
    console.log(newAddressNameValue); 
});
```

[A working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/L8tubddu/)

Answer (score 0):

You just placed your console logs at wrong places and the code below shows that your oldVal and newVal are both present.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $el = $('#inputAddressName');
  var oldAddressNameValue = $el.data('oldVal', $el.val());
  console.log(oldAddressNameValue.data("oldVal"));
  var newAddressNameValue = $el.change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newValue = $this.data('newVal', $this.val());
    console.log(newAddressNameValue.data("newVal"));
    console.log(newAddressNameValue.data("oldVal"));

  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputAddressName" value="123" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data` function returns the jQuery wrapped element. If you want to get the actual stored value, you should use `$el.data(key)` instead.

Here is what you need to do:

```
var $el = $('#inputAddressName');
$el.data('oldVal', $el.val());
$el.change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('newVal', $this.val());
    console.log($this.data('oldVal'));
    console.log($this.data('newVal'));
});
```

And [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sheperson/jb8gpwcd/1/) too.

Answer (score 0):

To find the initial value of an `<input />`, in JavaScript, simply use the `defaultValue` property:

```
var input = document.getElementById('inputAddressName'),
    oldValue = input.defaultValue,
    newValue = input.value;
```

For example, in jQuery:

```
$('#inputAddressName').on('change', function () {
     var el = this,
         oldValue = el.defaultValue,
         newValue = el.value;
});
```

```js
$('#inputAddressName').on('change', function () {
  var el = this,
      oldValue = el.defaultValue,
      newValue = el.value;
  
  console.log(oldValue, newValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputAddressName" value="Default value" />
```

Or, instead, you can use `getAttribute('value')`, which returns the value from the HTML attribute (which isn't updated as the `value` changes, only the `value` *property* changes):

```js
$('#inputAddressName').on('change', function() {
  var el = this,
    oldValue = el.getAttribute('value'),
    newValue = el.value;

  console.log(oldValue, newValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputAddressName" value="Default value" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var $el = $("#inputAddressName");
$el.data({"oldVal":$el.val(), "newVal":void 0});
var oldAddressNameValue = $el.data("oldVal")
, newAddressNameValue;

$el.on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data("newVal", $this.val());
    newAddressNameValue = $this.data("newVal");
    console.log(oldAddressNameValue, newAddressNameValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input id="inputAddressName" value="name1" />
```

Comment: I get the newAddressNameValue value when I put the console.log inside the $el.on..., but if I place it outside of it, at the bottom, the variable is not there anymore (local/global scope). Am I right? If so, how can I get the newAddressNameValue outside the change event?

Comment: `newAddressNameValue` should be `undefined` until _after_ a `change` event occurs. `console.log(oldAddressNameValue, newAddressNameValue);` , when composed directly after `$el.on("change", fn)` should run immediately , without waiting for a possible change event to occur . Once a change event does occur , `console.log(oldAddressNameValue, newAddressNameValue);` should return both values . If requirement to access `oldAddressNameValue` , `newAddressNameValue` at other `js` other than at original post , can  post other `js` ?